# Validate empty element and display alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Good Day

I have some issues with this script that looks for an empty element in a table -0 When the table is empty, it will display an alert 'empty'. If not, it must say 'not empty'.
However, the one I have here, displays the 'not empty' everytime - whether the table is empty or not...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var tds = jQuery("table.borderClass > tbody > tr > td");

            var anyEmpty = false;
            tds.each(function () {
                if (jQuery(this).text() == "")
                    anyEmpty = true;
            });

            if (anyEmpty == false || tds.length == 0) {
                alert('empty');
            }
            else {
                alert('NOT empty');
            }

        });
```

Thank you!

Comment: The logic in this code is weird. Shouldn't you be testing for `anyEmpty` to be `true` instead of `false`?

Comment: yeah you're right, but even when I set if (anyEmpty == True... it still does not work. It now keeps displaying the empty one, whether the table is empty or not

Comment: whether the table or table cells/columns are empty or not?

Comment: @David, well, it will alert `empty` if any cell in the table is empty. If none of your cells are empty, then are you sure that table contains an explicit `<tbody>` element? Try matching `table.borderClass td` instead.

Comment: @David Van Staden, you mean to say that if any <td> is empty then it should display empty and if it is not empty, it should display non-empty, do you want this separately for each <td> or you are checking empty table element?

Comment: you see, I want to check if either ALL td's (actually the spans inside) or NO td's are filled. So its all or nothing...